# Grammar of Off topic close reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

So [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/how-can-i-make-money-other-than-salary-through-internet-closed) question was closed at off topic, but the close reason took me back

> Questions on Programmers are expected
>   to **generally relate to indirectly
>   relate to programming**, within the
>   scope defined in the faq.

?

Comment: s/Grammer/Grammar/ ;-P

Comment: Related: [Problem with the site introductory text](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/119/problem-with-the-site-introductory-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing to:

> Questions on Programmers are expected to be about subjective issues in software development, within the scope defined in the faq.

Comment: That pretty much sums the site up. Thanks Jeff